# jsp pass session attribute to javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have javascript function inside JSP:

```
function confirmInput(projectname) {
    alert(projectname);
}
```

Inside JSP I have form with input:

```
<form onsubmit='confirmInput(<%="${sessionScope.project.name}"%>)' action="" method="get">
```

and session attribute **project.name**. 
Script does not work(((
How in right way to pass this value to javascript function? I have not found the answer among existing similar question(((

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form onsubmit='confirmInput("${sessionScope.project.name}")' action="" method="get">
```

or

```
<form onsubmit='confirmInput("<%=sessionScope.getAttribute("project").name%>")' action="" method="get">
```